# Facebook graph API - liking a Facebook page; can be achieved with correct authorisation?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I've read up about this everywhere, and the general consensus is that you are unable to like a Facebook page using any kind of API (but you can now like external pages via the graph api, as well as pages that link through to Facebook pages it would seem, e.g. I *can* create a like on here: http://facebook.com/40796308305).

However, while doing this research, I heard 'rumours' about apps being given the authorisation to like Facebook pages via oAuth or the graph API. Does anyone know this to be true?

Essentially, I have a page where a user must click on the 'like' button of a Facebook page, and then click a button to confirm they have liked it. The back-end then uses then authenticates the user for the app, and checks to see if the like exists on the page. If so, then a new page loads up. If not, they are redirected and asked to ensure they have clicked the like button.

Effectively, I would rather this process be done by telling the user that clicking the button will cause them to 'like' a Facebook page, and do it in one process.

Looking at the graph API, I could create a new 'action' to achieve the same effect, but as I understand it, unless they 'like' the Facebook page, they won't see posts from the page on their timeline.

Does anyone know if any 'rumours' of authenticated apps are true? If not, then what I'm talking about is probably not achievable; but I thought I would ask here first. Just trying to get a final word on the matter.

On a side note; if likes are not possible for pages, is there a way to generate an action, that also subscribes to a pages feed?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

> Essentially, I have a page where a user must click on the 'like' button of a Facebook page, and then click a button to confirm they have liked it. [...] Effectively, I would rather this process be done by telling the user that clicking the button will cause them to 'like' a Facebook page, and do it in one process.

Then why not just embed the JS SDK, and subscribe to the event of the user clicking the like button …? When you receive the event, then you can reload your page automatically via script.

For the rest of your question: TL;DR, and also not here to discuss “rumours”, sorry.

Comment: Mainly because there might be multiple 'like' buttons that need to be clicked, so detecting it using the JS SDK is fine but would rather a one-button job work. And as for the rumours, I'm just asking if there is any truth to them. But thanks for your reply.

Comment: Easy to adopt to checking multiple buttons …

Comment: Yes, but ideally wanted the one button solution for design and functional purposes.